# How to get the value from the input

Tags: jquery

I am trying to catch a change of input but it doesn't work with the button increase or decrease the value, what is the solution here?

```
<div class="container">
          <button id="tang" class="btn btn-success">+</button>
          <input type="text"  name="" id="number" value="1"">
          <button id="giam" class="btn btn-danger">-</button>
          <h1 id="show"></h1>
      </div>
```

```
$("#tang").click(function(){
            let result = parseInt($("#number").val()) +1 ;
            $("#number").val(result);
        });
        $("#giam").click(function(){
            let result = parseInt($("#number").val()) -1 ;
            $("#number").val(result);
        });

        $("#number").change(function(){
            $("#show").text($("#number").val());
        })
```

Comment: Not the issue but, you have an error in the html `value="1"">` should be `value="1"">`

Answer (score 6):

Please refer below code. You will need to trigger change event from increase and decrease button change.

```js
$("#tang").click(function() {
  let result = parseInt($("#number").val()) + 1;  
  $("#number").val(result).change();
});
$("#giam").click(function() {
  let result = parseInt($("#number").val()) - 1;  
   $("#number").val(result).change();
});

$("#number").change(function() {
  $("#show").html($("#number").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
          <button id="tang" class="btn btn-success">+</button>
          <input type="text"  name="" id="number" value="1"">
          <button id="giam" class="btn btn-danger">-</button>
          <h1 id="show"></h1>
      </div>
```

Comment: The solution is repeated numerous code unnecessarily. Check [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60294366/9071943) to have more options.

Comment: I refeerred the exact code that is asked in question, rather than introducing new functions and showing my skills on optimization.

Comment: Here solution required was why change is not being detected. Not writing different code.

Comment: Yeah, It's up to you. From my point of view, the above code  is hard to follow. It depends on the OP's decision. Happy coding.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it will be easier for OP to follow the code in my answer as it's his own code except addition from me, the missing code. And thank you for your suggestion too. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

It is working for me. Here is the working code at: https://jsfiddle.net/297s50gk/

Did you include jQuery in your page?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <button id="tang" class="btn btn-success">+</button>
  <input type="text"  name="" id="number" value="1"">
  <button id="giam" class="btn btn-danger">-</button>
  <h1 id="show"></h1>
</div>


$("#tang").click(function(){
  let result = parseInt($("#number").val()) +1 ;
  $("#number").val(result);
});
$("#giam").click(function(){
  let result = parseInt($("#number").val()) -1 ;
  $("#number").val(result);
});

$("#number").change(function(){
  $("#show").text($("#number").val());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix you could add an event trigger to your lines in the button `.click` functions like

```
$("#number").val(result).change();
```

You could go further and combine the two `click()` functions into one (with an `if` clause for increasing/decreasing the value).

Answer (score 0):

There is a **typo** in your code and wrap your all function inside in document.ready.

typo in this line
 `<input type="text"  name="" id="number" value="1"">` //remove one double quote.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#tang").click(function(){
             var container=$("#number");
            let result = parseInt(container.val()) +1 ;
            container.val(result);
            container.val(result).change();
        });
        $("#giam").click(function(){
            var container=$("#number");
            let result = parseInt(container.val()) -1 ;
            if(result<0)
              result=0;
            container.val(result);
            container.val(result).change();
        });

        $("#number").change(function(){
            $("#show").text($("#number").val());
        })
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
          <button id="tang" class="btn btn-success">+</button>
          <input type="text"  name="" id="number" value="1">
          <button id="giam" class="btn btn-danger">-</button>
          <h1 id="show"></h1>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options

1. Trigger [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event like `$("#number").change()`. However, your code is repeated numerous code unnecessarily.
2. You should refactor code like below.

```js
$("#tang").click(function(){
    let result = parseInt($("#number").val()) + 1 
    AssignThenDisplayValue(result);
});
$("#giam").click(function(){
    let result = parseInt($("#number").val()) - 1 ;
    AssignThenDisplayValue(result);
});

$("#number").change(function(){
    AssignThenDisplayValue($("#number").val());
});

function AssignThenDisplayValue(value){;
  $("#number").val(value);
  $("#show").text(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
          <button id="tang" class="btn btn-success">+</button>
          <input type="text"  name="" id="number" value="1">
          <button id="giam" class="btn btn-danger">-</button>
          <h1 id="show"></h1>
      </div>
```